# Find Value of $|A^3+B^3+C^3|$ , Given $|A -B|\neq 0$

Tags: matrices

> If $|A-B|\neq 0, A^4=B^4,C^3A=C^3B,B^3A=A^3B,$

> Then $|A^3+B^3+C^3|$ is

What I have try

$\displaystyle C^3A=C^3B\Longrightarrow C^3(A-B)=O$

$\displaystyle |C^3(A-B)|=0\Longrightarrow |C^3||A-B|=0$

Means $|C^3|=0$

And $\displaystyle A^4-B^4=0\Longrightarrow (A-B)(A+B)(A^2+B^2)=O$

$\displaystyle |(A-B)(A+B)(A^2+B^2)|=0$

$|A-B||A+B||A^2+B^2|=0\Longrightarrow |A+B||A^2+B^2|=0$

Now I did not understand how can I find value of $|A^3+B^3+C^3|$

Please help me , Thanks

Comment: You don't know whether $A^4 - B^4 = (A - B)(A + B)(A^2 + B^2)$ holds or not, since $A$ and $B$ may not commute.

Comment: What does $| \cdot |$ denote?

Comment: Are you sure it is $B^3A = AB^3$ instead of $AB^3 = BA^3$?

Comment: you have $\det(A^3+B^3+C^3) = \det(A^3+B^3)$ for sure. I am not sure the two given condition uniquely determines the RHS though.

Comment: @NikoWielopolski yes you are right.

Comment: What are $A,B,C$ (matrices?) and again, what does $|⋅|$ denote (determinant?)? Please edit your post to precise this, rather than in comments. And checked that the last hypothesis (edited by someone else) is what you intended.

Comment: You agreed to change $B^3A=AB^3$ to $AB^3=BA^3,$ but it has been changed to $B^3A=A^3B$ instead.

Comment: Without any mention of what kind of objects A, B, C are, this question is desperately in need of improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your correction now,
$$|(A^3+B^3+C^3)(A-B)| = (A^3+B^3)(A-B) + C^3A-C^3B| = |(A^3+B^3)(A-B)|$$
so
$$|A^3+B^3+C^3| = |A^3+B^3|$$ and the given conditions imply:
$$(A-B)(A^3+B^3) = 0\implies |A^3+B^3+C^3| = |A^3+B^3| = 0$$

Comment: The question needs clarifications before being answerable. (See comments.)

Comment: $|A|$ as a determinant is a known notation. And with conditions such as $B^3A = A^3B$, it's rather safe to assume OP is talking about matrices.

Comment: I thought the same, but it is the OP's duty to clarify this. They have been asked several times.  The reader (and potential answerer) is not in charge to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since you have $AB^3 = BA^3$, then
$$ A^4-B^4 = A^4 + AB^3 - BA^3 - B^4 = (A-B)(A^3+B^3)$$
So
$$|A^4 - B^4| = |A-B| |A^3 + B^3| \implies |A^3 + B^3| = 0$$

You have already showed that $|C^3| = 0$, so

$$0 \leq | A^3 + B^3 + C^3|  \leq |A^3 + B^3| + |C^3| = 0 + 0 = 0 \implies |A^3+B^3+C^3| = 0$$

Comment: Why is $| A^3 + B^3 + C^3|  \leq |A^3 + B^3| + |C^3|$? (And what are you assuming $|\cdot|$ means?) The question needs clarification before being answerable. (See comments.)

Comment: @AnneBauval I understand $|\cdot |$ to be some norm

Comment: And you assume it is multiplicative... Btw, what kind of objects are $A,B,C$ supposed to be?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, from the reasoning presented by the author. IMO probably matrices, but I don't want to assume anything. Hopefully the solution works for elements of any normed space

Comment: The author did not use inequalities, but seems to have gone away. $|\cdot|$ might be the determinant. Who will ever know?